# How do I exclude files from unit test

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Hi I am trying to exclude a file from the karma coverage report
I have looked through the web and people say the following line should work

in Karma.conf.js

```
 preprocessors: {
      'web/scripts/**/*.js': ['coverage'],
      'app/scripts/exp/!(expfile|fun).js': ['coverage']
 },
```

However, I still see them in my code coverage report.

I am not sure how to exclude them as my coverage percentage are greatly affected by these two files.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the directories - files you want to exclude are not loaded by any other include.